# insertAtomicBlock keeps inserting the atomic block at the start of the content

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Whenever I insert an image using insertAtomicBlock, the image always appears at the start of the content, instead of at the selection.

Currently my code is like this:

```
const entityKey = editorState
    .getCurrentContent()
    .createEntity('IMAGE', 'MUTABLE', {
        src: src,
        height: imgHeight + (imgHeight === 'auto' ? '' : 'px'),
        width: imgWidth + (imgWidth === 'auto' ? '' : 'px')
    })
    .getLastCreatedEntityKey();
onChange(AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(editorState, entityKey, ' '));
```

Comment: Try making your question more clear. Include necessary information including what framework or library you are using

Answer (score 0):

draftjs use immutable for model management. Your code not apply the updated content to editorState.